# Search over json object (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a search bar which updates the set of json entries depending upon query. Here's the code that displays the video list (`<Videos videos={this.state.data}/>`). When the page loads, I want to call `<Videos videos={this.state.data}/>`, but after this query from search bar should update this list. My search functionality is not working for some reason.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    data: [],
    filteredData: []
  };

  handleInputChange = event => {
    const query = event.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const filteredData = prevState.data.filter(element => {
        return element.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
      });

      return {
        query,
        filteredData
      };
    });
  };

  getData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/videos')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const filteredData = data.filter(element => {
          return element.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });
        this.setState({
          data,
          filteredData
        });
      });
  };

componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchForm">
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder="Search for..."
            value={this.state.query}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <Videos videos={this.state.data}/>
        <div>{this.state.filteredData.map(i => <p>{i.name}</p>)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to react, any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new object without the data property and setting that object as the state whenever you are calling this.setState. So the data property is getting deleted.

On the handleInputChange method do this:

```
 return {
       ...this.state,
        query,
        filteredData
 };
```

And on the getData method do this:

```
 this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          data,
          filteredData
 });
```

Comment: He doesn't mutate the state. He creates a new object for the state but without `...this.state`

Comment: You're right. I updated the answer. Thanks @RukkiesMan.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.state.data` in the `Videos` component which you got from the  server. You should use `this.state.filteredData` to show entries depend on `query`:

```
<Videos videos={this.state.filteredData}/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion along with EVeras helped. I can only mark one answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `handleInputChange` to `this`.
Look at [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) for more on this.